# Changing a field in a many to many relation table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello I am having a hard time debugging my code. What I need to do is create a page where the user will type in a last name and the system will return information related to it. I already have two fields working correctly the last field however is giving me trouble. The last field was originally going to come from the room table but now I need to change it to the rate table. I am not sure what files I need to go into to change the room to rate If someone could help me I would appreciate it!

First the output page Need to change

```
<%= booking.room.description %>
```

to

```
<%= booking.rate.cost %>
```

(I am getting a undefined method `room')

```
<h1>Bookin#bookout</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/bookin/bookout.html.erb</p>

 <center><table width = 65% border = 1> 
 <tr> <th> Customer Name</th><th> Room Number </th>  <th> Cost </th></tr>   
   <% @customer_list.each do |customer| %> 
<% customer.bookings.each do |booking| %> 
<tr> 
<td> <%= customer.last %> </td> 
<td> <%= booking.apple.roomnumber %> </td> 
<td> <%= booking.room.room_level %> </td> 
</tr> 
<% end %> 
<% end %>

  </table>
  </center>
```

Here is Customer model

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address, :city, :country, :course, :first, :last, :state, :takerint, :zip

  validates :address, :city, :country, :first, :last, :course, :state, :takerint, :zip, presence: true

  has_one :account
  has_many :courses, :through => :registrations
  has_many :registrations

  def takersvsint
   "#{first} - #{last} - #{takerint}"
  end



end
```

Here is booking model

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base 


  belongs_to :apple 
  belongs_to :customer 
  belongs_to :rate

end
```

Here is apple model

```
class Apple < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :customers, :through => :bookings 
    has_many :bookings
end
```

Here is the rate model

```
class Rate < ActiveRecord::Base

 validates :season, :room, :cost, presence: true 

 has_many :bookings
 has_many :customers, :through => :bookings

end
```

I think the problem lies in my schema but I do not know how to change it. There should be no room_id

```
create_table "bookings", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "customer_id", null: false
    t.integer  "room_id",     null: false
    t.integer  "apple_id",    null: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "bookings", ["apple_id"], name: "index_bookings_on_apple_id"
  add_index "bookings", ["customer_id"], name: "index_bookings_on_customer_id"
  add_index "bookings", ["room_id"], name: "index_bookings_on_room_id"
```

Comment: can you post these models so that the relation between them can be understood.

Comment: I have just updated them

Answer (score 0):

Generate a migration as:-

```
rails generate migration AddRateIdToBookings rate_id:integer
```

will generate

```
class AddRateIdToBookings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :bookings, :rate_id, :integer
  end
end
```

And run the migartion or customise it before running migartion

Comment: Do I have to migrate it after?

Comment: Yes you have to migrate it as rake db:migrate

Answer (score 0):

Generate a migration to add reference to `rates` in `bookings` table as :

```
rails generate migration AddRateRefToBookings rate:references
```

This will generate a migration as below:

```
class AddRateRefToBookings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :bookings, :rate, index: true
    remove_reference :bookings, :room, index: true   ## Add this line in migration
  end
end
```

Add `remove_reference :bookings, :room, index: true` line in the migration as suggested above to remove the reference `room_id` from `bookings` table.

After this run `rake db:migrate`